# How do you remove MacPorts and all the packages it has installed?

Tags: macos, macports

I have installed MacPorts on my Mac OS X Lion, and I would like to remove it.
There should be no more trace of MacPorts?

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: See: https://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.uninstalling.html

Answer (score 39, accepted):

From the manual, [uninstalling MacPorts](http://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.uninstalling.html) works as follows. You need to first uninstall all ports:

```
sudo port -fp uninstall --follow-dependents installed
```

If `port` is not found, try `/opt/local/bin/port` instead.

Also, to remove remainders of MacPorts, you will need to delete the following files by this single command (copy and paste line-by-line to Terminal):

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/local 
sudo rm -rf /Applications/DarwinPorts 
sudo rm -rf /Applications/MacPorts 
sudo rm -rf /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.* 
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/DarwinPorts*.pkg 
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MacPorts*.pkg 
sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/DarwinPortsStartup 
sudo rm -rf /Library/Tcl/darwinports1.0 
sudo rm -rf /Library/Tcl/macports1.0 
sudo rm -rf ~/.macports
```

**Warning:** Don't run a `sudo` command—especially a `rm -rf` one—unless you know what it's doing, and enter each line individually if you're unsure.

Note that MacPorts [creates its own user and user group](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/31013). They can be removed, too. See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/320714/611) over on Ask Different for more info.

Finally, each port installed through MacPorts may again create its own user and group, so you may have to perform a manual cleanup.

Comment: I did this and: `$ brew doctor` gives: `Warning: Setting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH can break dynamic linking.
You should probably unset it.`

Comment: Interesting. Did you ever set it? Like, in the bash profile, bashrc, etc?

Comment: No, BRAND NEW OS install too, this is something macports did, I think. However, echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH spits out paths to a mysql binary

Comment: It could have also been some rake or rails stuff, but I highly doubt it.

Comment: Hm, unfortunately I've never used MacPorts so I'm not quite familiar with it, but setting the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` for MySQL is pretty common indeed and probably required (?). You're not running Homebrew and MacPorts parallely, are you? In any case, it's just a warning, so unless you encounter specific errors it's best to leave it as-is. That being said, you should probably unset `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` if you really don't need it. I'm pretty sure it's in some way connected to MySQL or your .bashrc, .profile, etc. since this isn't set by default.

Comment: what about getting rid of /opt/local??

Comment: @Chet The above commands will remove said directory.

Comment: isn't there stuff in there besides macports?

Comment: @Chet Unless you put something there, no. `/opt/` does not even exist in a default OS X installation, so you can safely remove it.

Comment: Note that macports also creates its own user and group (see https://trac.macports.org/ticket/31013 ) and removing them is described over in https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/317576/how-to-delete-macports-user-after-using-the-migration-assistant . Also note that installed ports may themselves may create new users and groups...

Comment: @Anon Wow, what a mess, glad that I switched to Homebrew years ago.

Comment: @slhck ... :-) Could you add a note to your answer that there might still be a left over macports user and group after your uninstall steps if you think it might help someone?

Comment: @Anon Sure, done!

Answer (score 7):

This guide helped me remove MacPorts: 
http://bitboxer.de/2010/06/03/moving-from-macports-to-homebrew/

Here's a summary (in case the link goes dead):
First, uninstall MacPorts:

```
sudo port -f uninstall installed
```

Second step: remove everything that is left from MacPorts (check for MySQL and other stuff in /opt/local first):

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/local
sudo rm -rf /Applications/DarwinPorts
sudo rm -rf /Applications/MacPorts
sudo rm -rf /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/DarwinPorts*.pkg
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MacPorts*.pkg
sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/DarwinPortsStartup
sudo rm -rf /Library/Tcl/darwinports1.0
sudo rm -rf /Library/Tcl/macports1.0
sudo rm -rf ~/.macports
```

After that you should remove the /opt/local/bin from your $PATH

Comment: Can you summarize what is at the link in your answer in case the link goes dead?

Comment: Everywhere I look, there's "if you have a working port command, then use sudo port blah". What if, like in my case, port isn't working?

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694395/sudo-port-command-not-found ?

Comment: Separate the sudo rm -rf long command into serveral short command works really good for me.

Comment: @frumbert I know it has been 2 years since your comment date. However for further reference, let me tell my story. Macports was running on my OSX Yosemite system which I upgraded to El Capitan. Then, I decided to remove macports completely. For this, I reinstalled macports for El Capitan, then I followed what is told in the above answer. Hope this can help someone ;-)