# Uninstalling macports on Mojave

Tags: macports, macos-mojave

I am trying to uninstall MacPorts on my Mac and I have found the [protocol](https://superuser.com/questions/367434/how-do-you-remove-macports-and-all-the-packages-it-has-installed) to do so. However, I am getting an error:

```
user:~ femto-13$ sudo port -fp uninstall --follow-dependents installed
Password:
Error: Current platform "darwin 18" does not match expected platform "darwin 17"
Error: If you upgraded your OS, please follow the migration instructions: https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration
OS platform mismatch
    while executing
"mportinit ui_options global_options global_variations"
Error: /opt/local/bin/port: Failed to initialize MacPorts, OS platform mismatch
```

the proposed solution was to install a new version of ports and [erase the old one](https://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.uninstalling.html)

```
user:~ user-13$ sudo port -fp uninstall --follow-dependents installed
Password:
Error: No ports matched the given expression
```

And now the original recommended command doesn't even work.

Does anyone know what else can be done to get rid of MacPorts?

Answer (score 0):

The command is working and telling you that you have no installed ports.

If you now want to delete base, just `sudo rm -rf /opt/local` (or whatever the prefix was that you installed to.